# Serverless-offline throws "Configuration error" or "Cannot read property 'options' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, aws-serverless, serverless-offline

I am trying to deploy a serverless REST API with NodeJS, AWS Lambda, API Gateway, RDS and PostgreSQL.

So far I've set up the PostgreSQL RDS successfully and before start writing the functions to handle the requests to the DB I thought it'd be a good idea to test a small function first locally to check if the requests are being handled correctly.

So in the root of the project, I installed serverless-offline:

> npm install serverless-offline

It threw several warnings during installation of the type:

> npm WARN deprecated @hapi/pez@4.1.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained

(I'm sorry if that information is irrelevant, I'm quite new and don't know what is important and what is not.)

Then I configured my **serverless.yml**:

```
service: serverless-node-postgres-rds-rest-api

app: serverless-app

frameworkVersion: '2'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

configValidationMode: error

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: hello
          method: get
```

And here's the **handler.js**:

```
'use strict';

module.exports.hello = async (event) => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
      {
        message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!',
        input: event,
      },
      null,
      2
    ),
  };

  // Use this code if you don't use the http event with the LAMBDA-PROXY integration
  // return { message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!', event };
};
```

And the problem arose upon running

> serverless offline

As it threw the error:

```
Serverless: Running "serverless" installed locally (in service node_modules)
 
 Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
 
  Configuration error at 'functions.hello.events[0].httpApi.path': value 'hello' does not satisfy pattern /^(?:\*|\/\S*)$/
 
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
 
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          darwin
     Node Version:              14.15.4
     Framework Version:         2.40.0 (local)
     Plugin Version:            4.5.3
     SDK Version:               4.2.2
     Components Version:        3.9.2
```

So I changed the path in **serverless.yml** to "path: /hello" and the error changed to:

```
Type Error ----------------------------------------------
 
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
      at module.exports (/Users/randresverap/Development/Node/serverless-node-postgres-rds-rest-api/node_modules/serverless/lib/utils/telemetry/generatePayload.js:133:66)
      at async PluginManager.run (/Users/randresverap/Development/Node/serverless-node-postgres-rds-rest-api/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:607:35)
      at async Serverless.run (/Users/randresverap/Development/Node/serverless-node-postgres-rds-rest-api/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:325:5)
      at async /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/scripts/serverless.js:634:9
 
     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
```

And if I change the path to "path: '*'" it throws that same last error.

I ran it again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable as suggested but the result is pretty much the same, no extra debugging information.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I have spent hours surfing the internet looking for a workaround but I didn't find any post solving this same error and the issues solved at forum.serverless.com give entangled information difficult to follow.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: As of 29/1/2022, `serverless-websockets-plugin` is deprecated. Refer to this link to get the updated docs: `https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/websocket/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upgrade to version 2.41.2 of serverless or greater this issue is resolved.

`npm i -g serverless@2.41.2`

Answer (score 2):

I've been getting the `Cannot read property 'options' of undefined` error while trying to work with a different Serverless plugin (`serverless-domain-manager`). Downgrading the version of Serverless to 2.38 or earlier seems to fix the issue.

Comment: I have raised as a bug on serverless project as this post suggests it is impacting multiple plugins and so perhaps an issue with serverless itself. https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/9473

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue, but after switching to a package-lock.json file (identical package.json) from a previous project the issue was resolved.  So I assume there's a dependency that's causing this issue, but sorry to say I haven't been able to identify what that dependency is