# Serverless Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-serverless

I'm trying to upgrade my serverless app from `1.51.0` to `2.7.0`

while deploying the app I'm getting the below error:

```
[08:39:38] 'dev:sls-deploy' errored after 9.85 s
[08:39:38] TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
    at module.exports (/home/jenkins/workspace/TMC-Broker/DEV/node_modules/serverless/lib/utils/telemetry/generatePayload.js:236:66)
    at PluginManager.run (/home/jenkins/workspace/TMC-Broker/DEV/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:685:9)
08:39:38.428520 durable_task_monitor.go:63: exit status 1
```

First I thought it might be due to plugins I updated the plugins but still not able to resolve.

Here is my serverless.yml:

```yaml
service: my-service

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-step-functions
  - serverless-es-logs
  - serverless-domain-manager
  - serverless-plugin-ifelse
  - serverless-prune-plugin
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  timeout: 30
  stage: dev
  region: us-west-2
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  endpointType: PRIVATE
  role: lambdaExecutionRole
  apiGateway:
    resourcePolicy:
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal: "*"
        Action: execute-api:Invoke
        Resource: "*"
      - Effect: Deny
        Principal: "*"
        Action: execute-api:Invoke
        Resource: "*"
        Condition:
          StringNotEquals:
            aws:SourceVpce:
              - "vpce-************"
  environment:
    APP_SERVICE: ${self:service}
    APP_ENV: ${self:custom.stage}
    APP_REGION: ${self:custom.region}
    BUCKET_NAME: ${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}-#{aws:accountId}-onboard-s3
    LOG_REQUEST_ID: "x-request-id"
custom:
  prune:
    automatic: true
    includeLayers: true
    number: 5
  serverlessIfElse:
    - If: '"${self:custom.stage}" == "uat"'
      Exclude:
        - functions.abc-handler
    - If: '"${self:custom.stage}" == "prod"'
      Exclude:
        - functions.abc-handler
  region: ${self:provider.region}
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  prefix: ${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
    includeModules: true
functions:
  ms4-handler:
    handler: src/apifunctions/my.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /hello
          method: ANY
      - http:
          path: /hello/{proxy+}
          method: ANY
resources:
  Resources:
    onboardingBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}-#{aws:accountId}-onboard-s3
        LifecycleConfiguration:
          Rules:
            - Id: expirationRule
              Status: "Enabled"
              ExpirationInDays: 10
```

Jenkins Deployment Steps:

```
#!groovy
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic

pipeline {
    agent {label 'ecs-tf12'}
    stage('Serverless Deploy') {
        agent {
            docker {
                label "ecs"
                image "node:10.15"
                args "-u 0:0"
            }
        }
        steps {
            script {
                sh 'node --version'
                sh 'npm --version'
                sh 'npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org'
                sh 'npm install -g serverless@2.7.0'
                sh 'npm list -g serverless'
                sh 'npm install -g typescript@3.9.10'     
                sh 'npm install'
                sh "npx gulp install-terraform-linux"                    
                sh 'cp -v serverless-private.yml serverless.yml'
                sh "sls create_domain --stage ${params.env}"
                sh "npx gulp ${params.env}:sls-deploy"
                sh 'cp -v serverless-public.yml serverless.yml'
                sh "sls create_domain --stage ${params.env}"
                sh "npx gulp ${params.env}:sls-deploy"
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

My Package.json

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Serverless Service",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tslint --project tsconfig.json **/*.ts && serverless package",
    "deploy": "tslint --project tsconfig.json **/*.ts && serverless deploy",
    "offline": "tslint --project tsconfig.json **/*.ts && serverless offline"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.10.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^4.0.0",
    "joi": "^17.4.0",
    "json-stream-stringify": "^2.0.4",
    "launchdarkly-node-server-sdk": "^6.4.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "serverless-domain-manager": "^5.1.1",
    "serverless-http": "^2.7.0",
    "serverless-step-functions": "^2.23.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.16",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3",
    "xml-js": "^1.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@hewmen/serverless-plugin-typescript": "^1.1.17",
    "@types/aws-lambda": "8.10.39",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/node": "^13.1.6",
    "@types/uuid": "^3.4.6",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1204.0",
    "execa": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "serverless": "^2.7.0",
    "serverless-es-logs": "^3.4.2",
    "serverless-offline": "^8.0.0",
    "serverless-plugin-ifelse": "^1.0.7",
    "serverless-plugin-typescript": "^1.2.0",
    "serverless-prune-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "serverless-webpack": "^5.5.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.10",
    "typescript-tslint-plugin": "^0.5.5",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "author": "The serverless webpack authors (https://github.com/elastic-coders/serverless-webpack)",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

I'm not able to figure out the reason and solution for this.
any Ideas?

[Found a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67454564/serverless-offline-throws-configuration-error-or-cannot-read-property-option): but it doesn't resolve as I'm using 2.7.0

Comment: after searching many places. I didn't find any answer so I **downgraded the Serverless version to 2.38** and issue was resolved.